# how to check the text in first two buttons equals to the text in third button

Tags: android

Here is my code .This doesn't work

```
button1.getText() + button2.getText() == button3.getText()
```

Comment: can you format properly the code?

Comment: `button[0].getText()+button[1].getText()==button[2].getText()` ... Intersting way to compare strings in java ... please, learn javas basics first

Comment: *why don't u tell the correct code* ... because similar question was already asked here ...

Comment: @Bhanu: It is the very basic of every programming language...

Comment: String str=button1.getText().toString() + button2.getText().toString(); button3.setText(str);

Comment: http://codepaste.net/qvmkf5            )

Comment: @kgandroid i want to compare the addition of text in first two buttons equal to text in third button

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals` to compare strings,

Try this,

```
String button1Text = button1.getText().toString();
String button2Text = button2.getText().toString();
String button3Text = button3.getText().toString();

if((button1Text + button2Text).equals(button3Text)){
    // strings are equal
} else {
    // strings are not equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

button[6].getText().toString().equals(button[0].getText().toString().concat(button[3].getText().toString()));

Comment: Please use formatting in the future and put your code in code blocks. Also, your answer isn't helpful at all because it doesn't explain what's happening and doesn't help future users learn. You should add some (even if it's quick) explanation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with Strings in Java the operator **==** checks if the two objects refer to the same instance of an object.

While **equals()** checks if the two objects are actually equivalent, even if they are not the same instance.

try:

```
String button1Text = button1.getText().toString();
String button2Text = button2.getText().toString();
String button3Text = button3.getText().toString();

if (button1Text.equals(button3) && button2Text.equals(button3)) {
   // do something...
} else {
   // do something...         
}
```